# Mi algoritmo de busqueda a profundidad solo regresa la lista de grafos sin hacer el recorrido

Tags: c#, inteligencia-artificial

Mi codigo completo esta aqui:
https://github.com/josevqzmdz/mapas_IA_5

Necesito encontrar todos los caminos posibles de este mapa partiendo de una ciudad (vamos a referirnos a ellos como "nodos") de michoacan, mexico:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QczF.jpg

Tengo 2 objetos: 1 objeto nodo:

```
    string nombre { get; set; } 
    public nodo(string nombre)
    {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        vecinos = new List<nodo>();
        vertices = new List<vertice>();
    }
    public List<nodo> vecinos { get; set; }
    public List<vertice> vertices { get; set; }
    public int distancia { get; set; }
```

y 1 objeto vertice.

```
    nodo inicio { get; set; }
    nodo fin { get; set; }
    int distancia { get; set; } 

    public vertice(nodo inicio, nodo fin, int distancia)
    {
        this.inicio = inicio;
        this.fin = fin;
        this.distancia = distancia;
    }
```

Me tome el tiempo de mapear manualmente todos los nodos, los vecinos de dichos nodos y sus respectivas distancias (o pesos, aristas, como deseen llamarle):

```
static nodo aquila = new nodo("aquila");
aquila.vecinos.Add(maruata);
aquila.vecinos.Add(tepalcatepec);
// aquila - maruata
aquila.vertices.Add(new vertice(aquila, maruata, 2));
// aquila - tepalcatepec
aquila.vertices.Add(new vertice(aquila, tepalcatepec, 3));
```

Y asi sucesivamente con todas las ciudades.

Cree tambien una lista de adyacencia donde simplemente introduzco todas las ciudades:

```
    // lista de adyacencia
    public static List<nodo> listaAdyacencia = new List<nodo> {
        aquila, maruata, tepalcatepec, apatzingan, nueva_italia,
        lazaro_cardenas, los_reyes, uruapan, sahuayo, zamora,
        zacapu, patzcuaro, morelia, cd_hidalgo
    };
```

Ahora, he estado investigando por varios dias ya la logica del algoritmo de busqueda a profundidad y tengo una buena idea acerca de lo que hace. Recorre todas las aristas de todos los nodos, creando una lista aparte donde se guarda que nodo ha sido visitado ya, para evitar recorrer el mismo camino dos veces. Aqui esta el codigo que pude adaptar:

```
    // https://www.koderdojo.com/blog/depth-first-search-algorithm-in-csharp-and-net-core
    public List<nodo> busquedaProfundidad(List<nodo> grafo, nodo inicio)
    {
        List<nodo> nodosRecorridos = new List<nodo>();
        if (grafo.Contains(inicio))
        {
            return nodosRecorridos;
        }

        var stack = new Stack<nodo>();
        stack.Push(inicio);

        while (stack.Count > 0)
        {
            var vertice = stack.Pop();
            if (nodosRecorridos.Contains(vertice))
            {
                continue;
            }
            nodosRecorridos.Add(vertice);

            foreach(var vecino in grafo)
            {
                if (!nodosRecorridos.Contains(vecino))
                {
                    stack.Push(vecino);
                }
            }
        }
        return nodosRecorridos;
    }
```

Ahora, el problema es que, como tal cada uno de los nodos ya esta guardado en la lista de adyacencia. Por lo que el algoritmo no pasa del primer if. Se que este algoritmo es mas bien utilizado para explorar todas las posibilidades que no han sido hardcodeadas, pero como tal mi clase de IA me pide utilizarlo. ¿Que es lo que me esta fallando del rompecabezas? Y, ¿como podria imprimir en consola los nodos ya visitados?

Comment: Tu preguntas: ¿Que es lo que me está fallando del rompecabezas? Pues el primer if, como que lo tienes claro. Te falta la negación ( ! ),   if ( ! grafo.Contains(inicio)) Esto es para validar que el nodo existe en el grafo, porque si no existe no es muy inteligente iterar todo el algoritmo, ya sabemos que no hay camino posible

Comment: @Yussef tienes toda la razon, muchismas gracias.

Comment: A que te refieres cuando dices "Necesito encontrar todos los caminos posibles" ??  Porque puede entenderse como las aristas que son 18 o son todas le permutaciones posibles, o es otra cosa??? Podrías dar un pequeño ejemplo?

Comment: O quizás es la matriz de adyacencia el resultado que quieres??

Comment: @Yussef simplemente quiero imprimir todos los caminos que un nodo puede recorrer en el grafo, con las distancias que el nodo necesita recorrer. Por ejemplo (no es un ejemplo exacto a como esta en el codigo pero mi cerebro no da para mas ahorita mismo) de aquila a maruata es una distancia de 3, de aquila a lazaro cardenas es una distancia de 3 + 3 (porque primero pasa por maruata).

Comment: Pero aquila a lazaro cardenas hay varios camino, debo suponer que es más corto?

Comment: @Yussef tienes razon, para el mas corto voy a utilizar dijkstra, pero por mientras necesito mapear todos los caminos posibles.

Comment: en el codigo de las vertices esta esto: this.distanciaVecinos = inicio.nombre + " - " + fin.nombre + " = " + distancia.ToString(); no se como podria imprimir esto en consola

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posiblemente esta no sea la solución a tu problema, pero creo que te va a encaminar. El propósito es ordenar el código y su lógica, para que mediante pocos cambias puedas retornar distintos elementos (nodos, caminos, distancias) que son finalmente los elementos con que necesitas trabajar

***1.- Clase Nodo***

Estuve revisando tu código y me parece que solo necesitas crear una Clase (Nodo) y se vería así:

```js
public class Nodo
{
    public Dictionary<Nodo, int> vecinos { get; set; } = new Dictionary<Nodo, int>();
    public string nombre { get; set; }
    public Nodo(string nombre) => this.nombre = nombre;
        
    public static void SetVecinos(Nodo nodo1, Nodo nodo2, int distancia)
    {
        nodo1.vecinos.Add(nodo2, distancia);
        nodo2.vecinos.Add(nodo1, distancia);
    }

    public IEnumerable<(Nodo,Nodo,int)> GetTodosLosCaminos()
    {
        List<Nodo> nodosRecorridos = new();
        Stack<(Nodo nodo, int distancia)> stack = new();

        stack.Push((this,0));

        while (stack.Count > 0)
        {
            var vertice = stack.Pop();
                yield return (this, vertice.nodo, vertice.distancia);
                if (nodosRecorridos.Contains(vertice.nodo))
            {
                continue;
            }
            nodosRecorridos.Add(vertice.nodo);

            foreach (var vecino in vertice.Item1.vecinos)
            {
                if (!nodosRecorridos.Contains(vecino.Key))
                {
                    stack.Push((vecino.Key, vecino.Value + vertice.distancia));
                    
                }
            }
        }
            
    }
}
```

***2.- Inicialización de la aplicación***

```js
internal class Program
{
       
    static Nodo aquila = new Nodo("aquila");

    static Nodo maruata = new Nodo("maruata");
    static Nodo tepalcatepec = new Nodo("tepalcatepec");
    static Nodo apatzingan = new Nodo("apatzingan");
    static Nodo nueva_italia = new Nodo("nueva italia");
    static Nodo lazaro_cardenas = new Nodo("lazaro cardenas");
    static Nodo los_reyes = new Nodo("los reyes");
    static Nodo uruapan = new Nodo("uruapan");
    static Nodo sahuayo = new Nodo("sahuayo");
    static Nodo zamora = new Nodo("zamora");
    static Nodo zacapu = new Nodo("zacapu");
    static Nodo patzcuaro = new Nodo("patzcuaro");
    static Nodo morelia = new Nodo("morelia");
    static Nodo cd_hidalgo = new Nodo("ciudad hidalgo");

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Nodo.SetVecinos(aquila, maruata, 2);
        Nodo.SetVecinos(aquila, tepalcatepec, 3);
        Nodo.SetVecinos(maruata, lazaro_cardenas, 3);
        Nodo.SetVecinos(lazaro_cardenas, nueva_italia, 5);
        Nodo.SetVecinos(nueva_italia, apatzingan, 5);
        Nodo.SetVecinos(nueva_italia, patzcuaro, 3);
        Nodo.SetVecinos(apatzingan, tepalcatepec, 3);
        Nodo.SetVecinos(apatzingan, uruapan, 3);
        Nodo.SetVecinos(tepalcatepec, los_reyes, 3);
        Nodo.SetVecinos(los_reyes, sahuayo, 2);
        Nodo.SetVecinos(los_reyes, uruapan, 3);
        Nodo.SetVecinos(uruapan, zamora, 2);
        Nodo.SetVecinos(sahuayo, zamora, 3);
        Nodo.SetVecinos(zamora, zacapu, 4);
        Nodo.SetVecinos(zacapu, patzcuaro, 2);
        Nodo.SetVecinos(zacapu, morelia, 2);
        Nodo.SetVecinos(patzcuaro, morelia, 2);
        Nodo.SetVecinos(morelia, cd_hidalgo, 3);

    

       foreach(var n in aquila.GetTodosLosCaminos())
      {
          Console.WriteLine($"De {n.Item1.nombre} hasta {n.Item2.nombre} : {n.Item3}");
      }
            
    }
}
```

***3.- Explicación de la clase nodo***

Un nodo guarda sus vecinos en un diccionario, cuya clave es el nodo vecino y el valor es la distancia

¿Cuál es la distancia de aquila a maruata?

respuesta: aquila[maruata]

(eso solo para nodos vecinos)

Luego tenemos la función GetTodosLosCaminos(), que retorna un IEnumerable<(Nodo,Nodo,int)>, donde el primer nodo es el nodo inicial del camino y el segundo el final; y la distancia es la distancia desde el primer punto (en el ejemplo aquila) hasta el nodo final

Usar IEnumerable me permite hacer un "yield return" (que es uno de los tantos motivos porque C# es el mejor lenguaje de todos los tiempo), que lo que hace es básicamente poder retornar valores mientras recorro algo

***4.- Salida***

```
De aquila hasta aquila : 0
De aquila hasta tepalcatepec : 3
De aquila hasta los reyes : 6
De aquila hasta uruapan : 9
De aquila hasta zamora : 11
De aquila hasta zacapu : 15
De aquila hasta morelia : 17
De aquila hasta ciudad hidalgo : 20
De aquila hasta patzcuaro : 19
De aquila hasta nueva italia : 22
De aquila hasta apatzingan : 27
De aquila hasta lazaro cardenas : 27
De aquila hasta maruata : 30
De aquila hasta patzcuaro : 17
De aquila hasta sahuayo : 14
De aquila hasta apatzingan : 12
De aquila hasta sahuayo : 8
De aquila hasta apatzingan : 6
De aquila hasta maruata : 2
```

***5.- Variantes***

Hacerlo de esta manera, te permite modificar el código rápidamente para buscar otro tipo de respuestas

Por ejemplo

Que nos vaya retornando los **nodos visitados** hasta el momento

```
public IEnumerable<List<Nodo>> GetTodosLosCaminos()
    {
        List<Nodo> nodosRecorridos = new();
        Stack<(Nodo nodo, int distancia)> stack = new();

        stack.Push((this,0));

        while (stack.Count > 0)
        {
            var vertice = stack.Pop();
            if (nodosRecorridos.Contains(vertice.nodo))
            {
                continue;
            }
            nodosRecorridos.Add(vertice.nodo);
            yield return nodosRecorridos;
            foreach (var vecino in vertice.Item1.vecinos)
            {
                if (!nodosRecorridos.Contains(vecino.Key))
                {
                    stack.Push((vecino.Key, vecino.Value + vertice.distancia));
                }
            }
        }
            
    }
```

```
foreach(var nodos in aquila.GetTodosLosCaminos())
{
    foreach(var n in nodos)
    {
        Console.Write($"{n.nombre} > ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"");
}
```

Resultado:

```
aquila >
aquila > tepalcatepec >
aquila > tepalcatepec > los reyes >
aquila > tepalcatepec > los reyes > uruapan >
aquila > tepalcatepec > los reyes > uruapan > zamora >
aquila > tepalcatepec > los reyes > uruapan > zamora > zacapu >
aquila > tepalcatepec > los reyes > uruapan > zamora > zacapu > morelia >
aquila > tepalcatepec > los reyes > uruapan > zamora > zacapu > morelia > ciudad hidalgo >
aquila > tepalcatepec > los reyes > uruapan > zamora > zacapu > morelia > ciudad hidalgo > patzcuaro >
aquila > tepalcatepec > los reyes > uruapan > zamora > zacapu > morelia > ciudad hidalgo > patzcuaro > nueva italia >
aquila > tepalcatepec > los reyes > uruapan > zamora > zacapu > morelia > ciudad hidalgo > patzcuaro > nueva italia > apatzingan >
aquila > tepalcatepec > los reyes > uruapan > zamora > zacapu > morelia > ciudad hidalgo > patzcuaro > nueva italia > apatzingan > lazaro cardenas >
aquila > tepalcatepec > los reyes > uruapan > zamora > zacapu > morelia > ciudad hidalgo > patzcuaro > nueva italia > apatzingan > lazaro cardenas > maruata >
aquila > tepalcatepec > los reyes > uruapan > zamora > zacapu > morelia > ciudad hidalgo > patzcuaro > nueva italia > apatzingan > lazaro cardenas > maruata > sahuayo >
```

También podrías querer retornar la Pila, la cual te mostrará cómo funciona el algoritmo de profundidad. Si haces eso, obtendrás un resultado como este

```
aquila >
maruata > tepalcatepec >
maruata > apatzingan > los reyes >
maruata > apatzingan > sahuayo > uruapan >
maruata > apatzingan > sahuayo > apatzingan > zamora >
maruata > apatzingan > sahuayo > apatzingan > sahuayo > zacapu >
maruata > apatzingan > sahuayo > apatzingan > sahuayo > patzcuaro > morelia >
maruata > apatzingan > sahuayo > apatzingan > sahuayo > patzcuaro > patzcuaro > ciudad hidalgo >
maruata > apatzingan > sahuayo > apatzingan > sahuayo > patzcuaro > patzcuaro >
maruata > apatzingan > sahuayo > apatzingan > sahuayo > patzcuaro > nueva italia >
maruata > apatzingan > sahuayo > apatzingan > sahuayo > patzcuaro > lazaro cardenas > apatzingan >
maruata > apatzingan > sahuayo > apatzingan > sahuayo > patzcuaro > lazaro cardenas >
maruata > apatzingan > sahuayo > apatzingan > sahuayo > patzcuaro > maruata >
maruata > apatzingan > sahuayo > apatzingan > sahuayo > patzcuaro >
maruata > apatzingan > sahuayo > apatzingan > sahuayo >
maruata > apatzingan > sahuayo > apatzingan >
maruata > apatzingan > sahuayo >
maruata > apatzingan >
maruata >
```

También puedes retornar nodo a nodo (que vendría siendo lo mismo que un camino)

```
foreach (var vecino in vertice.Item1.vecinos)
{
    if (!nodosRecorridos.Contains(vecino.Key))
    {
        stack.Push((vecino.Key, vecino.Value + vertice.distancia));
        yield return (vertice.nodo, vecino.Key, vecino.Value + vertice.distancia);
    }
}
```

Comment: noto que en setvecinos, nodo2 se introduce primero que nodo1. ¿porque? si lo inicializo alreves el codigo no funciona

Comment: @ayy_chemixd cópiame como lo tienes

Comment: nono, tu codigo funciona de maravilla, pero solo tengo esa duda porque la intuicion diria que primero va el nodo1 en el diccionario de vecinos. @Yussef

Comment: @ayy_chemixd Es que da lo mismo el orden. Desde el punto de vista del código no debería haber problema si los inviertes. Y desde el punto de vista lógico, el orden de inicialización de los nodos no tiene por qué determinar el orden final de estos. Además la función "SetVecinos" es lo que yo llamo "función utilitaria", cuyo único fin es facilitar "algo" desde el punto de vista del desarrollo. Esta función hace que me ahorre la mitad de líneas al setear vecinos. La funcionalidad "real" es nodo1.vecinos.Add(..) que es la función que pertenece al objeto (la otra es estática y pertenece a la clase)